# Sync Famework: how to enable bulk insert/update/delete stored procedures in Hub and spoke model

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, microsoft-sync-framework

I am using MS Sync framework 2.1 in hub-spoke model with SQL Server 2008 and bunch of SQL Server 2008 Express clients.

The SyncAgent uses `DbServerSyncProvider` as the `RemoteProvider`.

Is there a way to enable bulk insert/delete/update stored procedures in this scenario to do the serverside operations, instead of processing data row by row?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

the Bulk operations in Sync Framework were only introduced in the collaboration/peer-to-peer database providers (SqlSyncProvider) in v2.1.

If you want to use DbServerSyncProvider, you will have to write a custom provider to enable that functionality.

If you can, i suggest you move to using the SqlSyncProvider instead.

Comment: Hi JuneT, Could you please provide some pointers or code examples on writing custom provider to enable bulk operations on the server? thank you

Comment: I dont have code but the way it works in the SqlSyncProvider is that there is a UDT (table) and this is populated from the change dataset and this UDT is passed as a parameter (TVP)  to the stored procs. if i may asked, are you using a custom SqlExpressClientSyncProvider? afaik, there is no SqlExpress provider counterpart for the DBSErverSyncProvider. If i were you, i'd move to using the SqlSyncProvider instead as it supports bulk change application out of the box.

Comment: But I am using SyncAgent and not SyncOrchastrator. For the SyncAgent, the RemoteProvider should be something descending from SyncProvider (like ServerSyncProvider) and not SqlSyncProvider. Please advise..

Comment: So are you using a custom client provider for your SqlExpress? Sync Fx doesnt ship with a provider for Sql Express using the Sync Agent. IMHO, moving to SyncOrchestrator/SqlSyncProvider is easier than to customize DBServerSyncProvider to use bulk operations.